# How to customize NbLayoutComponent by extending it to a new class

Tags: angular, nebular

I would like to have the footer full screen width, rather than the width of the contents section ([screen width - sidebar width](https://ibb.co/GvYgHmW)). Is there any way to do this?

I am using [Nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/getting-started/what-is-nebular#what-is-nebular) to build my app.

I couldn't find any option in Nebular docs to do this. So I tried extending the nbLayoutComponent, named it customNgLayoutComponent, and customized it to my desired template layout and used it wherever nb-layout is used. I am not sure this is the right way of customizing a component from a library.

I basically copied the original template of the nbLayoutComponent from the source https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/framework/theme/components/layout/layout.component.ts and tweaked it a little (placed `<ng-content select="nb-layout-footer"></ng-content>` in layout div instead of content div).

I am expecting the component template to be overridden with my custom template. But it does not work. Is this how you override the template of a component from a library? Do I have to also copy all the functions in nbLayoutComponent to make my customNbLayout work?

Comment: have you found a solution ? nebular does not provide solution out of the box for this even though to me it's like a basic needed functional. You can do styles for nb-layout-footer making it display: abs, left: 0 -> right: 0 and bottom: 0 with z-index, but i dont like this solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without extending `NbLayoutComponent`.

Take out the footer component and place it under `nb-layout`:

```
<nb-layout-footer>
  ... footer component
</nb-layout-footer>
```

And adjust the size of sidebar or `.main-container` under sidebar and make the footer width `100%`.

```
nb-sidebar .main-container {
   height: calc(100vh - height-of-your-footer)
}

nb-layout-footer {
   width: 100%
}
```

**What's happening:** You might have the following layout:

```
<nb-layout>
  <nb-layout-header subheader>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </nb-layout-header>
  <nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar" tag="menu-sidebar" responsive>
    <nb-menu tag="menu" [items]="items"></nb-menu>
  </nb-sidebar>
  <nb-layout-column class="layout-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </nb-layout-column>
  <nb-layout-footer>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </nb-layout-footer>
</nb-layout>
```

By placing the `nb-layout-footer` under the `nb-layout`, both `sidebar` and `.content` container are placed under `.layout-container` and each has defined width. The footer falls under `.content`. In order to make it full width you need to take the footer out of `.layout-container`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but this isn't working. No matter where you place nb-layout-footer, its always going to be rendered inside .contents. This is because in the layoutComponent they are using ng-content to choose the footer tag and place it in the content (check [this](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/d9a0ef79f136a3ed315a40cfcd04c4603d68598a/src/framework/theme/components/layout/layout.component.ts#L141) line in the library). Any other ideas will be highly appreciated because I am loosing my mind over this.

Comment: @bumchickbum97 The easiest way would be not using the `nb-layout-footer`. Use a simple container to hold your contents.